# How can I return a json object in an array if the value is being searched for

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

This is my first trying to implement HTTPS requests into code, so I am not 100% confident using this. So my goal to search for a term in my array with JSON objects and return everything associated with that value. Here is my code:

```
const campgrounds = [{
    name: "Three Rivers Petroglyph Site",
    town: "Lincoln, NM",
    lengthLimit: 25,
    elevation: 4986,
    numberOfSites: 7,
    padType: "gravel"
  },
  {
    name: "Baca Campground",
    town: "Lincoln, NM",
    lengthLimit: 32,
    elevation: 6397,
    numberOfSites: 7,
    padType: "dirt"
  },
  {
    name: "South Fork Campground",
    town: "Nogal, NM",
    lengthLimit: 19,
    elevation: 7513,
    numberOfSites: 60,
    padType: "unknown"
  }
]

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.query.q;
  console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);

  for (const campground of campgrounds) {
    if (campground == campgrounds.name) {
      res.json({
        campgrounds: campground
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad, first it is not really http request related, request is for request and yours the server side; secondly your post is not asking any question, explain your expectation; thirdly if you are looking for how to do filtering, search online, tutorials should be available everywhere.

Comment: are you trying to filter campgrounds array by searchTerm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid calling `res.json` inside loops. Generate the result (the array) instead and then call `res.json` at the end - outside the loop.

something like this

```
...

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  let searchTerm = req.query.q;
  console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);

  const results = []

  for (const campground of campgrounds) {
    if (campground.name == searchTerm) {
      results.push(campground);
    }
  }
  res.json({
     campgrounds: results
  })
});
```

Comment: So I this through and it returned an empty array

Comment: I need it to be to return all these objects  town, lengthLimit, elevation, numberOfSites, padType  based on the campground name searched.

Comment: Oh, Your `if` condition wasn't correct.. see the updated answer now

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this What worked for me, and ran it through Postman and it passed my tests

```js
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let searchTerm = req.query.q;
    console.log(`Search for ${searchTerm}`);

    // TODO

        for (const campground of campgrounds) {
                if (campground.name == searchTerm){
                        res.json(campground);
                }
        }
});
```

Here were the tests I ran via Postman:

```
pm.test("name check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.name).to.eql('Three Rivers Campground');
});
pm.test("length check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.lengthLimit).to.eql(25);
});
pm.test("elevation check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.elevation).to.eql(6332);
});
```